# ms word : hebrew words appear reversed

Tags: ms-word, hebrew

i am in the process of preparing a bilingual document [english/hebrew] using microsoft word 2000. part of the process involves taking existing text that appears on html pages. bizarrely, when i try to do this, the words appear in the sentences backwards. note that each individual word is spelled correctly, right to left ; however, their appearance in the sentence is reversed for some reason. as an example in english, if i were to paste `the quick brown fox`, what would appear is `fox brown quick the`. this happens whether or not i edit the html document directly from within word, or copy/paste from the html document into word.

i have made sure that right-to-left and hebrew language support is installed on the pc, and that the microsoft office language settings support the hebrew language. i've made sure that the language of the phrases in the word document are set to 'hebrew'. i've tried changing the text direction, no effect.

i've also consulted [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/925451/when-you-create-a-document-in-a-right-to-left-language-or-in-a-complex-script-language-by-using-word-2007,-and-then-open-the-document-in-word-2002-or-in-word-2000,-any-right-to-left-language-text-is-reversed) which seemed to address the issue, but the suggested fixes don't solve the problem.

does anyone have any ideas for other things i could try ?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the paragraph direction to RTL (and not just the text alignment)?
PS. This question belongs on superuser.com not stackoverflow.com

Comment: It is also possible that the HTML document you are using is using old "visual" hebrew style. If you post the HTML headers we might be able to help.

Comment: thank you for reply !  with your help i was able to solve the problem. i didn't know about the option to switch directions within a specific table cell until you pointed it out.
thank you as well for mentioning superuser.com, i didn't know about it before either. :)